# TensorFlow training - "Batch size" and tf.unpack - unpacking non "batch sized" dynamic values?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow-datasets

Hello TensorFlow friends.

***TL-DR:***

Im using Tensorflow 1.1.4 on Google collab with eager execution.

My training fails on the last batch of the first epoch because I have a forced batch size tf.unpack in my training loop which sometimes does not get a full batch, and fails on :

```
Epoch 1/5
147/148 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0133 - acc: 0.3863
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-133-bba4aeb63f3b> in <module>()
      1 steps_per_epoch=tf.ceil(len(all_image_paths)/BATCH_SIZE).numpy()
      2 
----> 3 history = model.fit(ds, epochs=5, steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch)

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError: Input shape axis 0 must equal 32, got shape [30]
     [[{{node unstack}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNextSync]
```

I can't figure out how to unpack a tensor containing `BATCH_SIZE` of file paths (string tensors) which I unpack, load and pre-process into `BATCH_SIZE` of image tensors:

```
def load_and_preprocess_image(batch_of_paths, batch_of_labels):

  # unpack our images from our batch
  list_of_paths = tf.unstack(batch_of_paths, num=BATCH_SIZE)
  list_of_images = []
  for path in list_of_paths:
      image = tf.read_file(path)
      if image == None:
        print("Unable to load image at path:" + path )
      image = preprocess_image(image)
      list_of_images.append(image)


  # repack our now loaded and processed images into a batch
  batch_of_images = tf.stack(list_of_images, 0)

  return batch_of_images,batch_of_labels
```

Is there a way to have my `BATCH_SIZE` be dynamically read from a variable that the dataset passes when a batch is not full? In my case, I request `BATCH_SIZE = 32`, but get `30` on my last pass - and then the abo

***LONGER / FULL CONTEXT***

Im using Tensorflow 1.1.4 on Google collab with eager execution.

I am attempting to train a model (multi class, multi label) against CSV data set which lists image file paths and then columns of labels being positively present, negatively present, or unknown.

Im also aware ,y data set also contains lots of unlabeled data (we'll address that later :)

The header and the first row looks like:

```
filepath,color_key_blue,color_key_green,color_key_luma,color_key_matte,color_saturation_desaturated,color_saturation_neutral,color_saturation_pastel,color_saturation_saturated,color_theory_analagous,color_theory_complementary,color_theory_monochrome,color_tones_blackwhite,color_tones_cool,color_tones_warm,exterior,exterior_airplane,exterior_airport,exterior_apartment,exterior_auto_body,exterior_beach,exterior_bicycle,exterior_boat,exterior_bridge,exterior_bus,exterior_bus_stop,exterior_canyon,exterior_car,exterior_castle,exterior_cathedral,exterior_cave,exterior_church,exterior_city,exterior_desert,exterior_farm,exterior_forest,exterior_glacier,exterior_helicopter,exterior_hospital,exterior_house,exterior_industrial,exterior_lake,exterior_library,exterior_mall,exterior_mansion,exterior_monastery,exterior_mosque,exterior_motorcycle,exterior_mountains,exterior_ocean,exterior_office,exterior_palace,exterior_park,exterior_parkinglot,exterior_pier,exterior_plains,exterior_playground,exterior_polar,exterior_port,exterior_restaurant,exterior_river,exterior_road,exterior_ruins,exterior_school,exterior_sidewalk,exterior_sky,exterior_skyscraper,exterior_space,exterior_spacecraft,exterior_stadium,exterior_station_gas,exterior_station_subway,exterior_station_train,exterior_store,exterior_suburb,exterior_synagogue,exterior_temple,exterior_theater,exterior_town,exterior_train,exterior_truck,exterior_tunnel,exterior_warehouse,exterior_wetlands,interior,interior_airplane_cabin,interior_airplane_cockpit,interior_airport,interior_arena,interior_auditorium,interior_auto_repair_shop,interior_bar,interior_barn,interior_bathroom,interior_bedroom,interior_boat,interior_bus,interior_cafe,interior_cafeteria,interior_car,interior_cave,interior_classroom,interior_cloister,interior_closet,interior_command_center,interior_commercialkitchen,interior_conferenceroom,interior_courtroom,interior_crypt,interior_dancefloor,interior_diningroom,interior_dungeon,interior_elevator,interior_factory,interior_foyer,interior_gym,interior_hallway,interior_helicopter,interior_hospital,interior_kitchen,interior_livingroom,interior_lobby,interior_mall,interior_meditation,interior_nave,interior_office,interior_office_cubicle,interior_office_open,interior_prayer_hall,interior_prison,interior_pulpit,interior_restaurant,interior_spacecraft,interior_stage,interior_stairwell,interior_station_bus,interior_station_fire,interior_station_police,interior_station_subway,interior_station_train,interior_store,interior_store_aisle,interior_store_checkout,interior_study,interior_subway,interior_synagogue,interior_throneroom,interior_train,interior_truck,interior_warehouse,shot_angle_aerial,shot_angle_eyelevel,shot_angle_high,shot_angle_low,shot_focus_deep,shot_focus_out,shot_focus_shallow,shot_framing_closeup,shot_framing_extemelong,shot_framing_extremecloseup,shot_framing_long,shot_framing_medium,shot_level_level,shot_level_tilted,shot_lighting_hard,shot_lighting_key_high,shot_lighting_key_low,shot_lighting_silhouette,shot_lighting_soft,shot_subject_animal,shot_subject_location,shot_subject_object,shot_subject_person,shot_subject_person_body,shot_subject_person_face,shot_subject_person_feet,shot_subject_person_hands,shot_subject_text,shot_timeofday_day,shot_timeofday_night,shot_timeofday_twilight,shot_type_master,shot_type_overtheshoulder,shot_type_portrait,shot_type_twoshot,texture_banded,texture_blotchy,texture_braided,texture_bubbly,texture_bumpy,texture_chequered,texture_cobwebbed,texture_cracked,texture_crosshatched,texture_crystalline,texture_dotted,texture_fibrous,texture_flecked,texture_frilly,texture_gauzy,texture_grid,texture_grooved,texture_honeycombed,texture_interlaced,texture_knitted,texture_lacelike,texture_lined,texture_marbled,texture_matted,texture_meshed,texture_paisley,texture_perforated,texture_pitted,texture_pleated,texture_porous,texture_potholed,texture_scaly,texture_smeared,texture_spiralled,texture_sprinkled,texture_stained,texture_stratified,texture_striped,texture_studded,texture_swirly,texture_veined,texture_waffled,texture_woven,texture_wrinkled,texture_zigzagged
path/to/image/-5.jpg,1,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
```

I am able to load the csv into a data set via `tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset` like so:

```
# make our data set
BATCH_SIZE = 32
FILE_PATH = ["filepath"]
COLUMN_NAMES = ["filepath", "color_key_blue","color_key_green","color_key_luma","color_key_matte","color_saturation_desaturated","color_saturation_neutral","color_saturation_pastel","color_saturation_saturated","color_theory_analagous","color_theory_complementary","color_theory_monochrome","color_tones_blackwhite","color_tones_cool","color_tones_warm","exterior","exterior_airplane","exterior_airport","exterior_apartment","exterior_auto_body","exterior_beach","exterior_bicycle","exterior_boat","exterior_bridge","exterior_bus","exterior_bus_stop","exterior_canyon","exterior_car","exterior_castle","exterior_cathedral","exterior_cave","exterior_church","exterior_city","exterior_desert","exterior_farm","exterior_forest","exterior_glacier","exterior_helicopter","exterior_hospital","exterior_house","exterior_industrial","exterior_lake","exterior_library","exterior_mall","exterior_mansion","exterior_monastery","exterior_mosque","exterior_motorcycle","exterior_mountains","exterior_ocean","exterior_office","exterior_palace","exterior_park","exterior_parkinglot","exterior_pier","exterior_plains","exterior_playground","exterior_polar","exterior_port","exterior_restaurant","exterior_river","exterior_road","exterior_ruins","exterior_school","exterior_sidewalk","exterior_sky","exterior_skyscraper","exterior_space","exterior_spacecraft","exterior_stadium","exterior_station_gas","exterior_station_subway","exterior_station_train","exterior_store","exterior_suburb","exterior_synagogue","exterior_temple","exterior_theater","exterior_town","exterior_train","exterior_truck","exterior_tunnel","exterior_warehouse","exterior_wetlands","interior","interior_airplane_cabin","interior_airplane_cockpit","interior_airport","interior_arena","interior_auditorium","interior_auto_repair_shop","interior_bar","interior_barn","interior_bathroom","interior_bedroom","interior_boat","interior_bus","interior_cafe","interior_cafeteria","interior_car","interior_cave","interior_classroom","interior_cloister","interior_closet","interior_command_center","interior_commercialkitchen","interior_conferenceroom","interior_courtroom","interior_crypt","interior_dancefloor","interior_diningroom","interior_dungeon","interior_elevator","interior_factory","interior_foyer","interior_gym","interior_hallway","interior_helicopter","interior_hospital","interior_kitchen","interior_livingroom","interior_lobby","interior_mall","interior_meditation","interior_nave","interior_office","interior_office_cubicle","interior_office_open","interior_prayer_hall","interior_prison","interior_pulpit","interior_restaurant","interior_spacecraft","interior_stage","interior_stairwell","interior_station_bus","interior_station_fire","interior_station_police","interior_station_subway","interior_station_train","interior_store","interior_store_aisle","interior_store_checkout","interior_study","interior_subway","interior_synagogue","interior_throneroom","interior_train","interior_truck","interior_warehouse","shot_angle_aerial","shot_angle_eyelevel","shot_angle_high","shot_angle_low","shot_focus_deep","shot_focus_out","shot_focus_shallow","shot_framing_closeup","shot_framing_extemelong","shot_framing_extremecloseup","shot_framing_long","shot_framing_medium","shot_level_level","shot_level_tilted","shot_lighting_hard","shot_lighting_key_high","shot_lighting_key_low","shot_lighting_silhouette","shot_lighting_soft","shot_subject_animal","shot_subject_location","shot_subject_object","shot_subject_person","shot_subject_person_body","shot_subject_person_face","shot_subject_person_feet","shot_subject_person_hands","shot_subject_text","shot_timeofday_day","shot_timeofday_night","shot_timeofday_twilight","shot_type_master","shot_type_overtheshoulder","shot_type_portrait","shot_type_twoshot","texture_banded","texture_blotchy","texture_braided","texture_bubbly","texture_bumpy","texture_chequered","texture_cobwebbed","texture_cracked","texture_crosshatched","texture_crystalline","texture_dotted","texture_fibrous","texture_flecked","texture_frilly","texture_gauzy","texture_grid","texture_grooved","texture_honeycombed","texture_interlaced","texture_knitted","texture_lacelike","texture_lined","texture_marbled","texture_matted","texture_meshed","texture_paisley","texture_perforated","texture_pitted","texture_pleated","texture_porous","texture_potholed","texture_scaly","texture_smeared","texture_spiralled","texture_sprinkled","texture_stained","texture_stratified","texture_striped","texture_studded","texture_swirly","texture_veined","texture_waffled","texture_woven","texture_wrinkled","texture_zigzagged"]
LABEL_NAMES = ["color_key_blue","color_key_green","color_key_luma","color_key_matte","color_saturation_desaturated","color_saturation_neutral","color_saturation_pastel","color_saturation_saturated","color_theory_analagous","color_theory_complementary","color_theory_monochrome","color_tones_blackwhite","color_tones_cool","color_tones_warm","exterior","exterior_airplane","exterior_airport","exterior_apartment","exterior_auto_body","exterior_beach","exterior_bicycle","exterior_boat","exterior_bridge","exterior_bus","exterior_bus_stop","exterior_canyon","exterior_car","exterior_castle","exterior_cathedral","exterior_cave","exterior_church","exterior_city","exterior_desert","exterior_farm","exterior_forest","exterior_glacier","exterior_helicopter","exterior_hospital","exterior_house","exterior_industrial","exterior_lake","exterior_library","exterior_mall","exterior_mansion","exterior_monastery","exterior_mosque","exterior_motorcycle","exterior_mountains","exterior_ocean","exterior_office","exterior_palace","exterior_park","exterior_parkinglot","exterior_pier","exterior_plains","exterior_playground","exterior_polar","exterior_port","exterior_restaurant","exterior_river","exterior_road","exterior_ruins","exterior_school","exterior_sidewalk","exterior_sky","exterior_skyscraper","exterior_space","exterior_spacecraft","exterior_stadium","exterior_station_gas","exterior_station_subway","exterior_station_train","exterior_store","exterior_suburb","exterior_synagogue","exterior_temple","exterior_theater","exterior_town","exterior_train","exterior_truck","exterior_tunnel","exterior_warehouse","exterior_wetlands","interior","interior_airplane_cabin","interior_airplane_cockpit","interior_airport","interior_arena","interior_auditorium","interior_auto_repair_shop","interior_bar","interior_barn","interior_bathroom","interior_bedroom","interior_boat","interior_bus","interior_cafe","interior_cafeteria","interior_car","interior_cave","interior_classroom","interior_cloister","interior_closet","interior_command_center","interior_commercialkitchen","interior_conferenceroom","interior_courtroom","interior_crypt","interior_dancefloor","interior_diningroom","interior_dungeon","interior_elevator","interior_factory","interior_foyer","interior_gym","interior_hallway","interior_helicopter","interior_hospital","interior_kitchen","interior_livingroom","interior_lobby","interior_mall","interior_meditation","interior_nave","interior_office","interior_office_cubicle","interior_office_open","interior_prayer_hall","interior_prison","interior_pulpit","interior_restaurant","interior_spacecraft","interior_stage","interior_stairwell","interior_station_bus","interior_station_fire","interior_station_police","interior_station_subway","interior_station_train","interior_store","interior_store_aisle","interior_store_checkout","interior_study","interior_subway","interior_synagogue","interior_throneroom","interior_train","interior_truck","interior_warehouse","shot_angle_aerial","shot_angle_eyelevel","shot_angle_high","shot_angle_low","shot_focus_deep","shot_focus_out","shot_focus_shallow","shot_framing_closeup","shot_framing_extemelong","shot_framing_extremecloseup","shot_framing_long","shot_framing_medium","shot_level_level","shot_level_tilted","shot_lighting_hard","shot_lighting_key_high","shot_lighting_key_low","shot_lighting_silhouette","shot_lighting_soft","shot_subject_animal","shot_subject_location","shot_subject_object","shot_subject_person","shot_subject_person_body","shot_subject_person_face","shot_subject_person_feet","shot_subject_person_hands","shot_subject_text","shot_timeofday_day","shot_timeofday_night","shot_timeofday_twilight","shot_type_master","shot_type_overtheshoulder","shot_type_portrait","shot_type_twoshot","texture_banded","texture_blotchy","texture_braided","texture_bubbly","texture_bumpy","texture_chequered","texture_cobwebbed","texture_cracked","texture_crosshatched","texture_crystalline","texture_dotted","texture_fibrous","texture_flecked","texture_frilly","texture_gauzy","texture_grid","texture_grooved","texture_honeycombed","texture_interlaced","texture_knitted","texture_lacelike","texture_lined","texture_marbled","texture_matted","texture_meshed","texture_paisley","texture_perforated","texture_pitted","texture_pleated","texture_porous","texture_potholed","texture_scaly","texture_smeared","texture_spiralled","texture_sprinkled","texture_stained","texture_stratified","texture_striped","texture_studded","texture_swirly","texture_veined","texture_waffled","texture_woven","texture_wrinkled","texture_zigzagged"]

def get_dataset(file_path, **kwargs):
  dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
      file_path,
      batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, # Artificially small to make examples easier to show.
      na_value="?",
      num_epochs=1,
      column_names=COLUMN_NAMES,
      ignore_errors=True, 
      shuffle=True, #TEMPORARY
      **kwargs)
  return dataset

csv_dataset = get_dataset(csv_file_path)
```

And then I transform the dataset to return a tuple of `string tensors` and `tensors` containing single dimensional vector of int32's containing my 1, 0 or -1's for each label:

```
# we need to split out our data set to matching file paths and the labels as a sparse vector for each label,
# containing 1, 0, -1 values for label concept present, label concept not present, dont know if present 

# for example, a CSV row like 
# FOLD_0/color_key_blue/1-5.jpg,1,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
# should return:
# * a tensor containing a path like data_root + FOLD_0/color_key_blue/1-5.jpg, 
# * a tensor of values [1,0,0,0, -1 etc]

# a function that returns a path, ordered dict of only the 

import tensorflow.python.util
def split_csv_to_path_and_labels(csv_row_Dict):
  print("Calling split_csv_to_path_and_label")

  filepath = csv_row_Dict.pop('filepath')
  data_root_tensor = tf.constant(data_root)

  filepath = tf.strings.join([data_root_tensor, filepath], separator='')

  #make a new tensor with the values of the LABEL_NAMES keys but packed into a 0, len(LABEL_NAMES) array
  labels = tf.stack(list(csv_row_Dict.values()), axis=1)

  return filepath, labels

#make a new data set from our csv by mapping every value to the above function
split_dataset = csv_dataset.map(split_csv_to_path_and_labels)
```

Finally, I need to make a data set that loads images for each string tensor in my batch and returns a batch of image / label tuples. I define a function to load the images like so:

```
def load_and_preprocess_image(batch_of_paths, batch_of_labels):

  # unpack our images from our batch
  list_of_paths = tf.unstack(batch_of_paths, num=BATCH_SIZE)
  list_of_images = []
  for path in list_of_paths:
      image = tf.read_file(path)
      if image == None:
        print("Unable to load image at path:" + path )
      image = preprocess_image(image)
      list_of_images.append(image)


  # repack our now loaded and processed images into a batch
  batch_of_images = tf.stack(list_of_images, 0)

  return batch_of_images,batch_of_labels
```

And then make a new data set by mapping the dataset to this function:

```
image_and_labels_ds = split_dataset.map(load_and_preprocess_image, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
```

Since the above function has a hard coded `BATCH_SIZE` it works until the last batch is smaller than the batch size and TF errors out which the error above.

How can I resolve this issue!?

Ive looked at [Dynamic batch size in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53422311/dynamic-batch-size-in-tensorflow) but its unclear to me how this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by using `tf.map_fn` and mapping a function that processes a single string tensor and returns a preprocessed (normalized) image tensor:

The main `tf.map_fn` call:

```
def load_and_preprocess_image_batch(batch_of_paths, batch_of_labels):
    batch_of_images = tf.map_fn(load_and_preprocess_single_image_from_tensor, batch_of_paths, dtype=tf.float32)
    return batch_of_images, batch_of_labels
```

And the declaration of `load_and_preprocess_single_image_from_tensor` and my preprocess code for anyone who cares:

```
IMG_SIZE = 224

  def preprocess_image(image):
  image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
  image = tf.image.resize(image, [IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE])
  image /= 255.0  # normalize to [0,1] range

  return image

def load_and_preprocess_single_image_from_tensor(path):
   image = tf.read_file(path)
   if image == None:
    print("Unable to load image at path:" + path )
   return preprocess_image(image)
```

And finally, ensure my data set uses the `load_and_preprocess_image_batch` function:

```
image_and_labels_ds = split_dataset.map(load_and_preprocess_image_batch, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
batch_of_paths = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.rand(30))

# SOLUTION 1
list_of_paths = tf.unstack(batch_of_paths, num=batch_of_paths.shape[0])
print(len(list_of_paths))

# SOLUTION 2
list_of_paths = tf.unstack(batch_of_paths, axis=0)
print(len(list_of_paths))
```

It is preferable ot use SOLUTION 2 than SOLUTION 1 as it will make independent of extracting shape as well.

Comment: Thanks, however axis=0 throws an error that its unable to determine the shape. Should have mentioned I tried that.

Ive resolved the issue with tf.map_fn and mapped a function to read a string tensor as a path and return an image tensor - which works for arbitrary batch sizes.